# How Can I Scrape a Website with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a list from a website but each dealership that I want to pull individually does not have a tag. Is there any way I could pull them so that they pull individually instead of as a list?

Here is the website that I am trying to pull from:

http://www.autodealerdirectory.us/ca_s_madd.html

Comment: you can use web  scraping tool like BeautifulSoup or Scrapy

Comment: Can you tell us the tags you want to scrape? Or at least tell us what exactly on the website.

Comment: Did you already manage to get them in a list?

Comment: @jxpython sorry so on the website I am trying to get all of the dealerships info pulled. they are all under the div id=bodyText when I pulled it they were all pulled at once but I want them one by one kinda how they are shown on the page.

Comment: @user9269112 hmm this is actually hard. The webpage has ugly html code

Comment: @jxpython yeah I have never had to work with such a messy webpage before do you have any suggestions for pulling this information cleanly?

Comment: @jxpython for cleaning this into a csv file would I just create a list then columns for the different fields to go into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.autodealerdirectory.us/ca_s_madd.html'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

dealers = []

for tag in soup.select('#bodyText hr')[1:]:
    s = ''
    s += tag.next_sibling
    s += tag.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling
    s += tag.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling
    s += tag.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling
    dealers.append(s)

for dealer in dealers:
    print(dealer.strip())
    print('-----------------------------------------')
```

This will do the job. The information of each dealer is in the list `dealers`. You just need to clean the string

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.